# Is there a way to make different bundles depending on the type of session logged?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

First, i have to say that i'm a novice in node and webpack and I'm looking for opinions and advices, not correct some particular code. So if you are patient with me i going to thank you very much. You see, i have to develop a web application in which there are different types of session and every one of them needs different modules of vue and some of them are shared (mine and third parties). I want to standarize my project but i just found information for single web applications, and yes, i'm looking for that but depending on the current session logged and a login page.

The project is middle developed in vanilla PHP 7, PostgreSQL as DBMS and Vue - Vuetify as a framework for javascript. I did some kind of frankenstein to compress the files needed to each session but i'm not confident that it is the better solution because each time the page is loaded, PHP has to compress the files. So now I want to try again with webpack. The problem is that I have seen in many places that webpack sumarizes the entire project in only one bundle and I don't want that.

I have to say also that i use CDN vue and vuetify so all vuetify's unwanted components are loaded.

Just for demostration this is my tree

```
api/                 # db connection, auth and ajax queries
src/                 # resources like images and some global css
views/               # here i have all the vue components and main pages depending on session
views/?/components/  # normal components (.js) All of them starts with Vue.component('name',{...})
views/?/routes/      # routed components (.js) All of them start with {...} (Vue-Router)
views/?/main.php     # Here I define the components and routes needed and I query the database some initial things.
views/?/main.js      # Vue-component that is loaded later

general_template.php # has the skeleton of all main.php, so each main.php when they are ready, load it at the end.
index.php            # check if session is active so can show a main page for each type of user.
```

Can you guide me which technologies i have to use in node? and how should i organize my files? Feel free to disorganize the entire tree if you think it is like an spagetti. Thank you beforehand.

Comment: You can use [vue router lazy load](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html). Or you could try to use [Building a Multi-Page App](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#building-a-multi-page-app) which might be better option in your case... In both cases it will be easier if you use [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/)

Comment: Maybe faster approach for you would be to just "cache" the files in production that php generates for sessions instead of loading them every time. On dev, you would keep it as is - generate files with php for sessions on every call. And for production, you would create cached files that php would serve (just save 3 generated files in some location, and serve them back from server). You can create simple script that will create the cache for production and that you can run from terminal. This would save you time if you already have everything in place and you just want to speed things up a bit